# Random words from array for Hangman

Tags: random

Oh, okay sooooo I need my method to specify the return of a struct for this to work?

Language is meant to be C#! :)

Ok, what exactly am I doing wrong here. I've tried a different things to return a random word from the array words but keep getting errors. The syntax appears to be similar to what I've read up on. Thanks.

```
    string GetRandomWords()
    {
        WordBook[] words = new WordBook[26];
        Random = new Random();

        return words[Random.Next(0, words.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Random syntax is missing. It should be as folows:

```
Random random = new Random();
return words[random.Next(0, words.Length)];
```

Also, your function specifies that it returns a string, but you return words[random], which is a struct. Hence the error

Comment: Okay, Minh. Thanks for that. Bear with me here a little. I have a struct  public struct WordBook
        {
            public int letters;
            public String word;
            public String hint;

        } Thought that when I assigned new WordBook (words) to [25] that would set the value of the array? This is the only line in the whole program that is giving an error. Cannot implicitly convert WordBook to int?